# Google charts in Angular JS controller not loading

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, ctrl

I am trying to load google charts in an Angular JS, but the webpage is returning 'Cannot draw chart: no data specified'

My HTML code is simply:

```
    <div ng-init="myChartObject.type='ColumnChart'">
    <div google-chart chart="myChartObject" style="height:200px;width:50%;"></div>
    </div>
```

I have the "myChartObject" defined in the controller, which loads up dependencies for 2 resources objects - Sensor, and AllSensors:

```
 angular.
 module('allCharts').
component('allCharts', {
templateUrl: 'all-charts/all-charts.template.html',
controller:['Sensor', 'AllSensors',
    function AllChartsController( Sensor, AllSensors) {
    var self = this;
    ....
        self.myChartObject = {};

        self.myChartObject.type = "ColumnChart";

        self.onions = [
            {v: "Onions"},
            {v: 3},
        ];

        self.myChartObject.data = {"cols": [
            {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
            {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
        ], "rows": [
            {c: [
                {v: "Mushrooms"},
                {v: 3},
            ]},
            {c: self.onions},
            {c: [
                {v: "Olives"},
                {v: 31}
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: "Zucchini"},
                {v: 1},
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: "Pepperoni"},
                {v: 2},
            ]}
        ]};

        self.myChartObject.options = {
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
        };
  }
]
```

});

I know the data is there because in the HTML I can write:

```
     <p>{{$ctrl.myChartObject.data}}</p>
```

And the data on the webpage comes back:

{"cols":[{"id":"t","label":"Topping","type":"string"},{"id":"s","label":"Slices","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"Onions"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"Olives"},{"v":31}]},{"c":[{"v":"Zucchini"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni"},{"v":2}]}]}

So what am I missing here? Why won't the chart load this data? I suspect something to do with my scope definition, I use var self= this, and then I can retrieve attributes from self using the $ctrl variable (not the usual $scope). Should it still work this way?

Comment: If you can access the data from html as `$ctrl.myChartObject` should you not also be using the `$ctrl` in the `chart` attribute? (and in the `ng-init` though really that sort of initialisation should be in the controller.)?

Comment: Ahhh yes, you are right - I needed to do <div google-chart chart="$ctrl.myChartObject" style="height:200px; width:50%;"></div></div>      And that worked. Thank you!